# How to enable HTTPS on Tomcat in a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, ssl, tomcat, https

I'm new to Tomcat and Docker, and am stuck trying to enable https on my website. First on the server, not in any container:

a) I generated a CSR

b) Acquired a commercial SSL certificate

c) Placed the certificates in a folder on the server /etc/docker/certs

d) Then created my Docker containers with the configuration below

I can use the command `docker exec -it <container-id> sh` to navigate my container. I can edit `server.xml` and `web.xml` but I realize I should install the certificates at the OS level outside the container if I want https configuration to persist past individual containers. In other words, I should be able to remove a container, and create another one without needing to reinstall the ssl.

How can I do this? Any ideas?. Thanks in advance! Below are my configurations:

1.Database

```
docker run -d --name=example-db --restart=always --net=example-net --mount type=volume,src=mydbdata,target=/example-db --hostname=example-db -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_USER=myuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret myapp/db
```

2.Application

```
docker run -d --name=example-app --restart=always --mount type=volume,src=mydata,target=/example-app -p 80:8080 --net=example-net -e DB_HOST=example-db -e DB_NAME=mydb -e DB_USER=myuser -e DB_PASSWORD=secret myapp/myapp
```

Again thanks for your help.
Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the external certs into a container at `docker run` time using [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#add-bind-mounts-or-volumes-using-the---mount-flag). Assuming your certs are in `/etc/docker/certs` on the host, and you want them to be at `/etc/ssl/certs` in the container, then add either of the following:

```
-v /etc/docker/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro
```

or

```
--mount type=bind,src=/etc/docker/certs,dst=/etc/ssl/certs,readonly
```

Your Tomcat config would use `/etc/ssl/certs` as its path in this case.